# reusing a variable defined in a python class

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

Let's say I define a class. I have a fun method, where I create self.x. I want to use self.x in a different method (reuse). How could I do that? Because I tried what I wrote and didn't work. Thanks!

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,t):
       self.t = t
    def fun(self):
       self.x = self.t+1
    def reuse(self):
       self.y = self.x
```

Comment: Unless `self.fun()` is ever executed, `self.x` is not defined, so you'll need to ensure that `self.fun()` has been called atleast once prior to calling `self.reuse()`

Comment: so it would have to something like this: self.y = self.fun()?

Comment: `self.fun()` doesn't return anything. So you'll just need to add `self.fun()` before the `self.y = self.x`

Comment: @rdas If he adds `self.fun()` before `self.y = self.x` it calls the `self.fun()` every time he calls `self.reuse()`, which can modify the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create all the variables in the `__init__` method.
Try this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,t):
       self.t = t
       self.x = 0
       self.y = 0
    def fun(self):
       self.x = self.t+1
    def reuse(self):
       self.y = self.x
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want. I made a simplistic example, but in fun(), I compute many things and that I want to reuse and not compute again. Let me ask another question though. In fun, what is the difference between making the assigment self.x = self.t+1 and x = self.t+1. I think I know but I'd like the confirmation of someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: `x = self.t+1` creates a local variable `x` in your method, that gets discarded when the method exits. `self.x = self.t+1` updates the value of your instance's `x` attribute. But according to this last question, it seems that you over-simplified the example in your question, and that it doesn't really ask what you want...

Comment: When you use `self.x = self.t+1` it will update the value of the class variable. When you use `x = self.t+1` it will create a local variable to that function, which you can't access outside.

Comment: Wait a minute. I think your answer is correct. If I write the class the way you did. is self.y = self.x = self.t+1 ? In other words, self.y = self.t+1? or self.y = 0? I guess I can just run this and see what happens.

Comment: When you mention `self.x = 0` in `__init__` it will just execute once once when the instance is created. when you call other functions it will return use the values which are calculated before.